# Why are the numeric input values added up using BufferedReader?

Tags: java

I tried to find out the maximum of four numbers from keyboard Input.

I used `bufferedReader` For some reason, the input numeric values add up instead of producing the maximum of them.

I tried to use a `Scanner` class and it worked as expected.

```java
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));

int a = in.read();
int b = in.read();
int c = in.read();
int d = in.read();

int n, m;

  if (a > b) {
    n = a;
  }
  else {
    n = b;
  }

  if (c > d) {
    m = c;
  }
    else {
    m = d;
  }

  int max = n > m ? n : m;

  System.out.println(max);
```

The output is the sum of all these input values but I expected only the maximum of them.

Comment: Where are you trying to get their max?

Comment: "_The output is ..._" There seems to be some missing code in the question. There is nothing here that does any output.

Comment: `in.read()` doesn't read numbers, it reads the byte value of the stream of characters. https://ideone.com/IzrS2v

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to run your code, if I output the values I see the numeric values of the characters I have entered.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int a = in.read();
        int b = in.read();
        int c = in.read();
        int d = in.read();

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(d);
        in.close();
    }
```

If I hit enter after each number I get

```
1
2
49
10
50
10
3
Process finished with exit code 0
```

After 1 and 2 I hit enter button - so the reader read 1 *enter* 2 *enter* and the output is 49 (numeric value for '1'), then 10 (numeric value for the new line symbol in my OS, Windows 10), 50 (numeric value for '2'). So, in fact, the numbers are not added up.

This is what you need (at least, one of the options)

```
    int a = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine());
    int b = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine());
    int c = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine());
    int d = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine());
```

Comment: Not ASCII but integer representation of the character input. This is because `BufferedReader#read` returns a byte and this value is widened to integer. Also, `BufferedReader#read` also reads the Enter key which can be `\n` or `\r\n` depending the OS.

Comment: You are right, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)

Comment: As a recommendation, please try to refer to a more up-to-date documentation. We're about to see Java 13 in this September, Java 7 is way outdated.

Comment: Please clarify is there any changes in the particular class?

Comment: Thanks, after using Integer.valueOf(). It works as expected.